# Dynamic updating templates

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am new to Adobe InDesign CS6 and are exploring the features. It is possible to create a template, then use it for a while and then update the template again and let the new update of the template be adapted to the current pages that already uses the template?

Comment: On "templates:": An InDesign template is an otherwise regular document but will by default be opened As Copy, whereas a regular document will by default open As Original (and you can override both). In other words, there is no "link" or "source" involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Templates are a one-direction mechanism.

You start from the template and then the template is no longer referenced. In other words, templates are only referenced when a *new* file is opened. They aren't "linked" to anything after that. Making changes to a template after the fact does *nothing* to alter any files previously started with that template.

That being posted, you can utilize things like object styles, paragraph styles, character styles, and the Library to store commonly used items.

> By the way, this would be a great feature to have... something like Global styles that are always referenced or linked to documents. Similar to how linked images function.

**EDIT:** It did just occur to me that if you use the **Book** command and all your files are merely chapters in the book, you do essentially get global styles. Any alteration to the *book styles* would be reflected in all chapter documents. Whether or not it is feasible to use the **Book** command for everything may be another matter though.

I'm also not clear about the question since you specifically mention "pages". If you mean you have different *pages* in *one document*, you can utilize **master pages** to configure a common template or theme for pages *in that document*. Altering a master pages *does* update any page which references that master, but again, only in *that* InDesign file. If you mean "pages" as in *separate InDesign documents*... then everything else in this answer applies.

Comment: And if I use the styles. Will I then get the same effect, ehwn updating the styles?

Comment: No. Files are never backwards thinking. Nothing in in the core functionality of InDesign is dynamic in that manner. Only linked images *within* an indesign file will update if the external image changes (actually, you'll be asked if you want to update them.)

Comment: Object, character, paragraph, table, and cell styles can manually be updated from *any* file, you have to select one. It will not automatically select the original template.

Comment: True, but realize they never alter any *existing* files with those styles in them. Altering styles only alters the open file. If no file is open, then it alters the *starting point* for that style in *new* files. There's no mechanism to alter old files already created other than opening them and manually updating them.